# Object.GetType throws NullReferenceExceptions

Tags: moles, pex

I'm trying to use Pex and Moles in my SharePoint project. However I'm facing problem when running Pex Explorations. I'm getting error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  at System.Type System.Object.GetType()
```

Additionaly in "Pex Exporations result" window i'm seeing 2 Reflection issues:

```
System.TypeLoadException: Method 'get_TargetType' in type 'System.ComponentModel.Moles.SBaseNumberConverter' from assembly 'System.Moles, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0ae41878053f6703' does not have an implementation.
```

at an attribute that decorates
    [module System.Moles.dll]

and

```
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
```

at an attribute that decorates
    [module System.Moles.dll]

Comment: `Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.`